# Data Type issue in one of the filelds in Table

Tags: oracle

One of my field has Data Type as Numeric and the size is (16,8). If I give the value as 0.000000012 will it take and load it in the table? As there are 9 places after the decimal.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: No I didn't as it is a prod couldn't replicate the same in test

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#g196646

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't replicate the same in test"? `create table tz (col number(16,8)); insert into tz values (0.000000012); select col from tz; drop table tz purge;` - are you a professional working with databases or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will accept and round the values (at least in 11g):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tst (c1 NUMBER(10,2));

Table created
SQL> INSERT INTO tst VALUES (9.123);

1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO tst VALUES (9.129);

1 row inserted
SQL> SELECT * FROM tst;

          C1
------------
        9.12
        9.13
```